# Login popup in javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jsp:

```
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Data Platform - Real Time Monitor </title>
    <script src="../dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js?ignore=notused30"></script>
    <script src="../dist/loadingGrid.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/sortGrid.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #popupbox{
          margin: 0; 
          margin-left: 40%; 
          margin-right: 40%;
          margin-top: 50px; 
          padding-top: 10px; 
          width: 20%; 
          height: 150px; 
          position: absolute; 
          background: #FBFBF0; 
          border: solid #000000 2px; 
          z-index: 9; 
          font-family: arial; 
          visibility: hidden; 
    }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         function login(showhide){
           if(showhide == "show"){
             document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
           }else if(showhide == "hide"){
             document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden"; 
           }
         }
    </script>
    <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0px;">
        <div id="popupbox"> 
           <form name="login" action="" method="post">
               <center>Username:</center>
               <center><input name="username" size="14" /></center>
               <center>Password:</center>
               <center><input name="password" type="password" size="14" /></center>
               <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" /></center>
           </form>
           <br />
          <center><a href="javascript:login('hide');">close</a></center> 
      </div> 
<p><a href="javascript:login('show');">login</a></p>     
<div style="font-style:bold;font-size:30;color:black;"> Data Platform - Monitor
```

But when I open the jsp, a link `"login"` appears on top, which on clicking shows a popup box for logging in, however I'm still able to see all the content of the page before logging in. How do I make this popup box appear before loading the content of the page?
Also, I want to set only one username and password and if only that is supplied, page should be displayed. How to get this done?

Comment: Did you tried to hide the form by default ? You did not run `login("hide")` in the first place. EDIT : Sorry, didn't see the popupbox div. Please work on the identation next time ;)

Comment: Yes, please clean up your indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your `login` and `close` links both have javascript in the `href` attribute, it should be in `onclick` attributes instead.

```
<a onclick="login('show');">login</a>
```

By having it in the `href` (or any other attribute that's not associated with an event) the code gets executed. Since your last button is `javascript:login('show');` it will always show the login.

Better yet, you should do all the work in your script.

```
document.getElementById('show-login').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click, but run the following code
    login('show');
});
```

This requires you added an `id` attribute to your login button.

```
<a id="show-login">login</a>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening after changing it to onclick. "login" isn't clickable now, so can't even get the popup on clicking it leave apart getting popup to appear before loading content of the page.